# What is the URI to load text file in WP7?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, path, uri

It so simple to show any image in WP7 using relative uri path. 
But loading a text file becomes a big questionmark.

Please look at the image and please try to help how the URI should looks like to have the file as string variable.

[image: Uri error]

```
        Dim S As String
        Dim U As New Uri("file:///Family_christmas;component/database/de/1.txt", UriKind.Absolute)
        Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(U.LocalPath, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
        S = sr.ReadToEnd
        sr.Close()
        Me.Title = S.Split(Environment.NewLine)(0)
        Me.Text = S.Substring(Me.Title.Length + Environment.NewLine.Length)
```

---

*** SOLVED THAT WAY ***

Declare file as ressource not as content. Then use the following code:

```
    Dim S As String
    Dim U As New Uri("database/de/1.txt", UriKind.Relative)
    Dim streamInfo As Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(U)
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(streamInfo.Stream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
    S = sr.ReadToEnd
    sr.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `StreamReader` looks for the file in the file system, not in resources. You can get a resource stream my **marking your text file as Resource** and using this code: (sorry for the vb to c# conversion :))

```
StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("file:///Family_christmas;component/database/de/1.txt", UriKind.Relative));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(info.Stream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show(text);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. You made my day!